# Android Emulator has no "network" command

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I launch an AVD, it doesn't seem to matter which one but I have tried Nexus 4 and with API 18 and 25, and then connect via telnet to send commands.  It connects fine, auth is fine, but then a command like "network speed edge" or "network speed full" results in:

```
KO: unknown command, try 'help'
```

Ok, fine I can look at the help, but there is no network-related command in the list of available commands:

```
help
Android console command help:

help|h|?         print a list of commands
crash            crash the emulator instance
kill             kill the emulator instance
quit|exit        quit control session
redir            manage port redirections
power            power related commands
event            simulate hardware events
avd              control virtual device execution
finger           manage emulator fingerprint
geo              Geo-location commands
sms              SMS related commands
cdma             CDMA related commands
gsm              GSM related commands
rotate           rotate the screen by 90 degrees
```

Additionally, I'm running the newest Android Studio, completely updated, on Linux Mint 18.1. Other commands like "geo" and "power" work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The network command is not already neccesary because the android studio provides you a tool bar from where you can change the network type.
It was so easy for me to do it. this tool bar shows up next to the emulator screen.